# Why is my category post repeating twice

Tags: loop

Im trying to output category with its post on a single page, but for some reason the post from all category are repeating in each category, what am i doing wrong here
Here the code:

```
<?php
        #Template Name: food
        get_header();
 ?>

<?php
        $taxonomy = 'category';
        $param_type = 'category__in';

        $term_args = array(
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'exclude' => 1
        );
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $term_args);
?>

<div class="row">
        <?php if($terms) : ?>

                <?php $counter = 0; foreach($terms as $term) : $counter++; ?>

                        <?php
                                $args = array(
                                        '$param_type' => array($term->term_id),
                                        'post_type' => 'food',
                                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                                        'posts_per_page' => -1
                                );

                                $my_query = null;
                                $my_query =  new Wp_Query($args);
                        ?>

                        <?php if($my_query->have_posts()) : ?>

                                        <?php if($counter == 2): ?>
                                                <ul class="menu-list sixcol last">
                                        <?php $counter = 0; else: ?>
                                                <ul class="menu-list sixcol">
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                                <h3><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>
                                                <?php
                                                        while($my_query->have_posts()): $my_query->the_post();
                                                        $post_meta_data = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                                                        $price = $post_meta_data['fangshsu_price'][0];
                                                 ?>

                                                        <li>
                                                                <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
                                                                <i><?php if($price) {echo '&pound;' . $price;} ?></i>
                                                                <?php the_content();?>
                                                        </li>

                                                <?php wp_reset_query(); endwhile; ?>
                                        </ul>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: A question should never rely on an external page. Please add the code to your question and add [debug information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: i 2nd that (but isnt it nice the code have line numbers? makes life a lot easier - should be on the to do list for sure.

Comment: @SagiveSEO : post that on [meta] if the point hasn't already been raised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a weird parameter in line 24 which i dont understand... did you copy paste this function from elsewhere?

anyhow...
**change line 24 from:**

```
'$param_type' => array($term->term_id),
```

**To this:**

```
'cat' => array($term->term_id),
```

Good luck and dont forget to read @toscho comment for future questions.

Comment: He has set `$param_type` earlier in the code (line 8). But you're right - wrapping it in single quotes will cause that param to fail.

Comment: thanks mate... searched for that (should have done it with chrome which simply highlights..) thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @vencoder your spot on the single quote was the culprit i removed it everything work good now. any advice on how to tidy up this code i feel it look messy